# What's a good way to pad this list of strings to the same length?

Tags: ruby

Here's a puzzle:
I have a list of strings each in a format:

```
\w+==============================\w+
```

The words on both sides of the `==============================` could be different lengths. What's a good way to pad each string with more `=` so that all strings have an equal length? There should be a minimum of 30 `=` characters in between the words.

ie, I have this list:

```
[ "Hello World==============================Bye!",
  "This==============================Should",
  "Be==============================Padded nicely!"]
```

Turned into:

```
[ "Hello World===============================Bye!",
  "This====================================Should",
  "Be==============================Padded nicely!"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [ "Hello World===============================Bye!",
  "This====================================Should",
  "Be==============================Padded nicely!"]

max = a.map(&:length).max
a.map{|l| l.sub(/(?:==)/, "=" * (max - l.length))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to pad each string with *more* `=` characters, so that all strings are the same length and every string has at least 30 `=` characters.  I would like to offer a solution that permits the number of `=`'s to decrease for some of the strings, so long as they are all padded to the same length, each string has at least 30 `=` characters and at least one string has exactly 30 `=`'s (recognizing that this might not work for you).  This produces a minimax solution for padded string length, subject to the two constraints.

**Code**

```
def pad(a, min_equals)
  b = a.map { |s| s.split(/=+/) }.map { |e| [e.join.size] + e }
  longest = b.transpose.first.max
  b.map { |(len,head,tail)| head + '='*(min_equals+longest-len) + tail }
end
```

**Example**

```
a = [ "Hello World==============================Bye!",
      "This==============================Should",
      "Be==============================Padded nicely!"]

pad(a,30)
  #=> ["Hello World===============================Bye!",
  #    "This====================================Should",
  #    "Be==============================Padded nicely!"]
```

**Explanation**

```
c = a.map { |s| s.split(/=+/) }
  #=> [["Hello World", "Bye!"], ["This", "Should"], ["Be", "Padded nicely!"]]
b = c.map { |e| [e.join.size] + e }
  #=> [[15, "Hello World", "Bye!"], [10, "This", "Should"],
  #    [16, "Be", "Padded nicely!"]]
d = b.transpose
  #=> [[15, 10, 16], ["Hello World", "This", "Be"],
  #    ["Bye!", "Should", "Padded nicely!"]]
e = d.first
  #=> [15, 10, 16]
longest = e.max
  #=> 16
b.map { |(len,head,tail)| head + '='*(30+longest-len) + tail }
  #=> ["Hello World===============================Bye!",
  #    "This====================================Should",
  #    "Be==============================Padded nicely!"]
```